# react-native keep scrollbar in the ScrollView After to update a list

Tags: react-native

I have a list with some data in the view scrollable.
label  -----  checkbox

If the user clicks on the checkbox, the button updates my reducer and refreshes the list to display if the checkbox is checked or not.

My problem concern the scrollBar, my scrollbar after every click is initialize on the top of my view.

I find a solution but ... it's not good

```js
let scrollY = 0
function FiltersScreen(props) {
    return (
      <View style={{height: "90%", padding: 10}}>
          <ScrollView style={{flexDirection: 'column', paddingRight: 5}}
                      ref={ScrollViewRef}
                      onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight) => {
                          crollViewRef.current.scrollTo({
                              y: scrollY,
                              animated: false,
                          });
                      }}
            // keep the scrollbar position
                      onScroll={event => scrollY = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y}
                      onScrollEndDrag={event => scrollY = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y}

          >
              // content
          </ScrollView>
      </View>
    )
}
```

It's possible to not refresh the scrollbar?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that
your FiltersScreen view is a subview in another view(let call MotherView).
when MotherView re-render, the FiltersScreen view is re-render too.

It makes your scrollview re-init.
You should prevent re-render on FiltersScreen view when MotherView re-render by:

split FiltersScreen view to other file and

```
export React.memo(FiltersScreen);
```

then import your FiltersScreen View and add to MotherView.

`React.memo` will prevent re-render in subView if props not use in subView.